# Joomla template folder not showing in template manager

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-template

I am trying to create a template.I have created a folder for template in templates folder and also created two files index.php and templateDetails.xml

My index.php has following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >  
<head>  
<jdoc:include type="head" />  
</head> 

<body>

<jdoc:include type="component" />  

</body>
</html>
```

and templateDetails.xml has following code which yes I copied because beginner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE install PUBLIC "-//Joomla! 1.5//DTD template 1.0//EN"  
 "http://dev.joomla.org/xml/1.5/template-install.dtd">  
<install version="3.1.5" type="template">  
       <name>template _tut</name>  
       <creationDate>31-01-2009</creationDate>  
        <author>Nettut Fan</author>  
        <authorEmail>your@email.com</authorEmail>  
        <authorUrl>http://www.siteurl.com</authorUrl>  
        <copyright>You 2009</copyright>  
        <license>GNU/GPL</license>  
        <version>1.0.0</version>  
        <description>Template Tut</description>  
        <files>  
                <filename>index.php</filename>  
                <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>  
                <filename>css/template.css</filename>  
         </files>         


        <positions>  
                <position>breadcrumb</position>  
                <position>left</position>  
                <position>right</position>  
                <position>top</position>  
               <position>user1</position>  
                <position>user2</position>  
                <position>user3</position>  
                <position>user4</position>  
                <position>footer</position>  
        </positions>  
</install>
```

My joomla version is 3.1.5 and despite doing above mentioned steps my template folder is not showing in template manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the template to register it completely.

There are 2 ways of doing this:

1. Download your files, zip them up and install it as you would any other extension.
2. In the Joomla backend, go to "**Extension Manager**", then "**Discover**". This will detect uninstalled extensions and should bring your template up in the list. check it and install it

Hope this helps